# Back up connection list in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I've got a problem with the available connections list in SQL Server Management Studio. There is a window with server name when you try to establish connection. I had like 20 of them saved and I only had to choose from the dropdown. After Management Studio was closed in an improper way, all connections are gone.

For the future, is there any way to back up these saved connections?

Comment: I think djhayman's response ought to be marked as an answer. Sure worked for me.

Answer (score 63):

Under the "View" menu, select "Registered Servers", and a new panel will appear. You can save servers in "Local Server Groups" (which is under "Database Engine") by right-clicking and selecting "New Server Registration". You can also select "New Server Group" if you want to organize your servers into groups.

In the future, just cancel out of the login window when you open SQL Server Management Studio, and double-click one of your saved servers to connect to it.

Comment: Tried, Export/Import, its not working